# Where I can check the age of this blended scotch whisky?

Tags: whiskey, age

How to check how old this scotch whisky is?

[image: Grant's Family Reserve Finest Scotch Whisky]

Comment: It's a blend, do you want to know when the bottle was made or the age of the youngest whisky in the blend?

Answer (score 14):

For blended whisky, the age is not generally considered a relevant factor. There will be a range of ages and whiskies in there, chosen to make the end result.

Unless a particular blend has ages specified (the Grant's Family Reserve doesn't), all you can guarantee is that the youngest whisky is 3 years old.

As an example, another Grant's whisky, the 12 year old, has whiskies that are 12 years old and older blended into it.